# Set initial size for collapsing toolbar, expand or collapse

Tags: java, android, androiddesignsupport, expandable, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using [android support design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to create a collapsing toolbar. It works great, my view collapses when I scroll and expands when I scroll back.

But I wonder, I would like to have a profile in this toolbar, but half the profile would be hidden at first. So for example at first you only see the users profile picture in the toolbar. If you scroll down the list the toolbar collapses and everything gets hidden. But if you scroll the other way, to the top of the list and kind of beyond, the toolbar will expand even more and show you both profile picture and more information like name, description and so on..

Is this possible? To set the toolbar like "half collapsed" or something similar.

Comment: Please post here if you figure it out, I'm looking for the same thing. Here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685750/android-collapsible-toolbar-set-how-much-the-toolbar-should-be-collapsed-in-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying and searching for information about the collapsing toolbar I ended up using another library instead.

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

With this I got the customisation I wanted by setting anchor points. Though I didn't get, or atleast I don't know how to get, the function of the toolbar expanding and changing from toolbar color to an image for example. But for my case, the customisation was the main function and thus more important.